# Are 短（い） and 身近（い・な） related?

Tags: words, etymology, homonyms

Is one derived from the other?  `身近` means - amongst other definitions - "close/near to one(self)", so it's not that much of a leap to say that something near to you is a "short" distance away, and get `短い` from that.  Is there any truth to this, or is it just coincidental?  Or this there some other kind of connection between these words?

- Bonus Question:  Does the correct spelling of `身近` use a `じ` or a `ぢ`?　[Related Discussion](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1238592582)

Comment: My guess is that it's coincidence. 身近 is probably spelt with a ぢ - 近 is ちか, and the ち undergoes 連濁.

Comment: You can find the kana spelling of 身近 in a [dictionary](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E8%BA%AB%E8%BF%91&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss).

Comment: @snailboat:  Obviously I've seen it both ways which is why I asked.

Comment: @Billy:  Except there are many words where `ち` does not 連濁 into `ぢ`, especially examples with `中` or `地`.

Comment: @istrasci Both of your examples are on-yomi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The historical spelling (歴史的仮名遣い) of 短い uses a じ instead of a ぢ, so this rules out the possibility of an etymological relationship between 短い and 身近.

Comment: Does that mean that up to the spelling reform in 1946, all spellings respected the etymological origin of a word?

Comment: Well, more precisely, there was a spelling reform in the Meiji era which restored spellings to etymological ones. Before that things were more haphazard.

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting. Do you have any sources, or at least a name, for this reform? Presumably in your answer you assume that this reform didn't overlook みじかい...

Comment: You can read about it [on Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%B4%E5%8F%B2%E7%9A%84%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E9%81%A3). 短い (or rather, 短くて) is attested in the Tale of Genji, so presumably they have taken the spelling from there.